# Handling Back Stack with NavGraphs in BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, navigation, bottomnavigationview

Title: Issue with duplicate back stack entries when using NavGraph instead of Fragment with BottomNavigationView in Navigation Component

Content:

I'm using the Android Navigation Component to implement a BottomNavigationView. Initially, when I linked each menu item to a Fragment, I managed the back stack so that Fragments would not be duplicated by setting setLaunchSingleTop(true). This setup worked as expected.

However, I encountered a problem when I switched from using Fragments to Navigation Graphs for each menu item. Even though I set setLaunchSingleTop(true) as before, this setting doesn't seem to work properly. Now, every time I switch between the tabs, a new Graph is added to the back stack. Also, it seems like the state saving is not working correctly.

Here is the Navigation Graph code I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        app:graph="@navigation/navigation_home" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        app:graph="@navigation/navigation_dashboard" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
        app:graph="@navigation/navigation_notifications" />
</navigation>
```

Upon inspecting the internal code of NavigationUI.setupWithNavController, I noticed that .setLaunchSingleTop(true) is already set. However, I'm not sure why it's not working as expected.